# Added Fabric/Crashlytics to new project but doesn't upload dSYM

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've just created a new iOS Swift project, using Xcode 7 beta-4, and have integrated [Crashlytics](https://get.fabric.io/crashlytics?locale=en-us) (part of [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/?locale=en-us) now) with the usual process.

It integrated all fine, and I can simulate crashes etc.

However when I go to the Crashlytics dashboard it warns me that:

> Missing dSYM
>
> We're missing a dSYM to process crashes, upload it here!

And none of the crashes show up.

Clicking the warning message (it's link is mentioned here: 
http://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/crashlytics.html#troubleshooting) gives me a list UUIDs Crashlytics is missing dSYMs for.

The page gives the option to upload a dSYM, which I have tried doing (getting it from /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos). However after doing so this does not resolve the issue.

I've tried getting the frameworks from CocoaPods instead of manually adding them, in case that made a difference. It didn't.

-

So my only thought is perhaps Crashlytics doesn't handle dSYMs produced by Xcode 7 beta? Or is there something fundamental I've overlooked?

Many thanks for your help!

-

**UPDATE:**

After many back and forth emails with the Crashlytics team, this particular problem was discovered by them to be caused by changes made in one the beta Xcode 7 versions. A fix to Crashlytics was pushed out and since then it worked.

If you're experiencing similar issues, I suggest first ensuring you're using a release version of Xcode, and also the latest version of Crashlytics :)

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. It sounds like you're doing everything right. I'd like to check our back end and see. Can you email me at support@fabric.io and include the dSYM you're uploading and let me know your bundle id?

Comment: Yes certainly Alex, will do, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Go to Build settings and choose Dwarf with dSym File option for both debug and release builds.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't uploaded dsym ..You can get dsym file from:

Goto https://itunesconnect.apple.com> SignUp> MyApps> Activity> Then select the version of App for which the Missing dsym error is showing and download the dsym file from there...

upload it to fabric

Hope so your issue is resolved..