# Uploading .dSYM on Fabric (crashlytics)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have integrated Fabric in my iOS application, after integrating (using `cocoa pods`) I need to upload `.dsym` file on Fabric account.I have uploaded `.zip` file of my `.dsym` on Fabric but still it is not reflected on the Fabric website. It says check after some time so I have checked around 1 hours later but its not working for me. If anyone have done kindly help me.
You can see in below images.

**Before uploading `.dsym`**

[image]

**After uploading `.dsym`**

[image]

Comment: Please see this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565527/added-fabric-crashlytics-to-new-project-but-doesnt-upload-dsym?rq=1

Also, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37292997/1484974
May this will help you.. !!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - if you reupload the dSYM once more, does that help?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I have done, but it didn't help me at all, So I have created a new version and upload for the new version. It works, some weird issue was there. But now another issue produced I have made the code for crash on button click. The application is crashed but don't know about fabric its not provided a message is 0 crashed for my new version (2.0)

Comment: Sounds like SO may not be the best place for this conversation then, want to move it to Twittercommunity.com/c/fabric or email support(at)fabric(dot)io?

Comment: Ok thanks I will do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your fabric](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: If you will notice carefully after you have uploaded the dsym, it still says processing (your second screenshot) but if you go back to your crash list, you will find that new crashes would be shown now (provided if you uploaded the correct dsym file in case multi dsym are missing)

Comment: Agreed with @UmarFarooque - u need to check back again in your dashboard and u see the list